# how to adjust text height to div using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some articles on the block. Some of them cut in the middle of their hight like on the picture:

[image]

I tried to fix this problem by using the function below, but it still doesn't work.

```
const setSameHeightToAll = function() {
    const all = document.querySelectorAll('.text_blog')
    let maxHeight = 0
    var length = all.length
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (all[i].getBoundingClientRect().height > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = all[i].getBoundingClientRect().height
      }
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      all[j].setAttribute('style', 'height:' + maxHeight + 'px')
    }
}
```

in html:(this is pug.js)

```
.text_blog
   != post.content.full
   p.read_more 
   a(href='/blog/'+post.key) leia mais >>
```

this is css:

```
.text_blog {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 112px;
}
```

How can I change my function to work correctly.

Comment: Why javascript and why not just `height: auto` on the css?

Comment: Your question is about HTML and CSS but, instead, you show the JavaScript that generates that. You would make your question more clear by showing the generated HTML and CSS instead.

Comment: @AbanaClara I cant get height: auto, because i will have all article post. I want to have only first few sentence. Rest I want to hide.

Comment: @Rob I add more code to the question. As you see the article are adding dynamically. I create html in pug.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the max-height to 0 in your javascript code.

Not knowing the full context of your code, because you only posted the javascript part, You may either have a constant height for all '.text_blog' elements or use

```
CSS
.text_blog{
  height: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

OR

```
JAVASCRIPT
const setSameHeightToAll = function() {
    const all = document.querySelectorAll('.text_blog')
    //GET HEIGHT OF FIRST ELEMENT AND MAKE IT UNIFORM
    let maxHeight = all.firstElementChild.offsetHeight;
    //SET CONSTANT HEIGHT
    let maxHeight = '500px';
    var length = all.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      all[i].setAttribute('style', 'height:' + maxHeight + 'px')
    }
}
```

You are also forgetting to include the closing ';' at the end of some lines.

Comment: thx for your answer. One more question.. I have an alert in console that i cant do offsetHeight because first element is undefinded. So i tried to do a loop and took first element, but it still doesnt work. Do you have any idea why my txt is cut again?